# procedure for Data-changed on a table acknowledge in Oracle database

Tags: oracle11g

**Hello all,**

I have a table named `EMP`, so I want to write a procedure which should give me the changed data (i.e if any Insert, Update or Delete happened on that table) in that table as an acknowledged output.

Comment: How do you identify "changed data"?  Particularly deletes?  Is there a trigger on the table that writes changes to a separate log table that you can query?  Have you enabled change data capture (CDC) for the table?  Are you publishing changes via Streams that could be subscribed to?

Comment: No there is no trigger for recording changes. No I didn't enabled CDC as I dont wann use that. Actually as per requirement this should be done using biztalk so I thought If I can create one procedure which gives me changed data so I will those records.